# i want to create e commerce site at first get the products from api by react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

that's my reducer page i'm getting virtual data from json place holder

```
    import axios from "axios";
var x = [];
axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(res => {
       x= res.data
        console.log(x)
    })

const initState = {
    count: 0,
    data: x


}


const reducer = (state = initState , action) =>{  }
```

/// app.js page :::

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    count: state.count,
    data : state.data

  }
}
```

i cant display the items in the app.js please help

Answer (score 0):

You should put the initial data into Provider component. It's usually done in index.js or App.js.
App.js should be class component and in componentDidMount() function make call to this API and get response. Then update store in provider to let redux know about initial state.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite work like that - you can't do async initialisation in your reducer. You can do it in your action file or component though.

```
const initState = {
    count: 0,
    data: x // x is loaded async so this won't work
}

const reducer = (state = initState , action) =>{  }
```

You could put it in an action file like this:

```
// assuming redux-thunk is installed
export const myAction = args => dispatch => {
  axios.get(...).then(results =>
    dispatch({type: 'INITIALISE_MY_DATA',
              payload: results}) )
}
```

You would then handle the `INITIALISE_MY_DATA` action in your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to dispatch changes, when you get data, so you can change state in reducer based on this action. 
Here is the code for

```
//do this in componentDidMount of your app root component
import axios from "axios";
//get data
var x = [];
axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(res => {
       x= res.data
        store.dispatch(type: "ACTION_TYPE", payload: x) //action type could be anything,

    })

//reducer
const initState = {
    count: 0,
    data: x
}

const reducer = (state = initState , action) =>{
    const newState = {...state};
    switch(action.type){
      case "ACTION_TYPE": //this should match action you have dispatched
        newState.count = action.payload.count;
        newState.data = action.payload.data;
        return newState;
    }
}
```

and in your component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class YourComponent extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
     <div>
       {this.props.data}
     </div>
    )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    count: state.count,
    data : state.data

  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```

Note that if your data is array, you probably should first map trough array and generate element for each value, for example:

```
render(){
let newData = [];
this.props.data.forEach((data, i) => {
    newData.push(<div> {data} </div>);
});
return(
{newData}
);
}
```